# PHP CURL on MAC - Hangs when curl_exec for localhost:1055

Tags: php, curl

I have been trying to call my website on localhost:1055 and my curl_exec call hangs. When I invoke external URL, it is working fine and I am getting a response. I have tried to turn off my firewalls, I have gone through all articles on stack overflow, but I don't seem to get an answer to this problem. I have seen one post where someone had similar issue but there was no resolution for that. Can anyone help?

I am on OS X Al Capitan version 10.11.6 (15G1004) with PHP 5.6 and I am using internal web server of PHPstorm running on port 1055. This is my code:

```
    <?php

    function __singleRequestSending($data, $options = array()) {

    // array of curl handles
    $ch = curl_init();
    // data to be returned

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $data["url"]);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 1055);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urldecode($data["data"]));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
    }

    $data = array(
        'url' => "http://localhost:1055/info.php",
        'data' => "abc" 
    );

    $res = __singleRequestSending($data);
    echo 123;
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($res);
    print_r($res);
   exit;


    ?>
```

Comment: Be a pretty strange firewall to block connections on the loopback device (localhost)

Comment: Firewall is completely turned off. So, that is not an issue

Comment: from browser when access http://localhost:1055/info.php ...  works ?

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue, and for the life of me could not figure out what was going on. Without knowing your exact situation, it's difficult to tell if our issues had the same root cause, and given that this is 7 years old, I think it's unlikely I'll be able to know. However, I'm sharing how I fixed my situation, as it was tricky to figure out, and I hope that it saves someone else time.

In my case:

1. I was using php's built-in web server to host my website. (I started the web server using `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000` on the command line, assigning it to port 8000.)
2. I was making an ajax call from my website to a php script (call it "script A") that was also being hosted by my that web server on port 8000.
3. script A is ultimately what called `curl_exec` to a separate php script (script B) which I was *also* hosting with that same web server. So, the url given to my curl handle was `http://localhost:8000/<path to script B>`. To be more specific, within script A, I had:

```
$curl = curl_init("http://localhost:8000/<path to script B on web server>");
// curl_setopt code...
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
```

4. The ajax call to script A would hang indefinitely on `curl_exec` and I'd have to restart the server. No php error logs. External cURL requests worked fine (i.e. if I set `curl_init` to go to any external URL it would work fine); it was only calls to localhost:8000 (or 127.0.0.1:8000) that would hang.

Turns out the issue (in my case) is that php's built-in web server is single threaded; it was getting deadlocked because it couldn't execute the cURL request, as the ajax request was in process, and thus the ajax request could not complete either. See this SO: [PHP Built-In Server Can't cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173953/php-built-in-server-cant-curl)

The way around this for me was very simple:

1. Start two separate php web servers, on different ports (i.e. `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000` in one console window and `php -S 127.0.0.1:7000` in another).
2. Host the website that will make the ajax call to script A on localhost:8000. (Script A would also be hosted by localhost:8000.)
3. In script A (which called `curl_exec` to cURL script B), make sure the URL given to `curl_init` was using port 7000 (the second server) NOT port 8000 (the first server, which script A is being hosted on).  i.e. inside script A:

```
$curl = curl_init("http://localhost:7000/<path to script B on second web server>");
// curl_setopt code...
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
```

No more deadlock; the ajax request is done on web server 1 (port 8000), whereas the cURL request is done on web server 2 (port 7000) and both can complete. Alternatively, could use something other than php's built-in web server to avoid this issue.

Comment: This is not only on a mac, it's general behaviour of PHP, see: [The web server runs only one single-threaded process, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php#:~:text=The%20web%20server%20runs%20only%20one%20single%2Dthreaded%20process%2C%20so%20PHP%20applications%20will%20stall%20if%20a%20request%20is%20blocked.)

Comment: Yes, I only just recently learned this. I should have mentioned that my situation was on Windows, not Mac.